# Add files in an existing workflow

Tags: alfresco

How to add files into an existing workflow in Alfresco Community Edition 5.0d** based on some **criteria** like **TagName** and **FileName**.

Actually, my requirement is, **I want to create a workflow with multiple files dynamically**.

Answer (score 1):

The key to adding files along the way is the workflow package.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Share_Workflow_UI#Package_Items

To summarize, in order for a workflow task to allow changes to the associated documents, you need to configure the "packageItems" for the task form. This will allow the user to associate more files with the workflow from the task screen.

If this doesn't make sense for you, I'd recommend doing some of the workflow forms tutorials Alfresco provides.

The workflow package is a node and can be programatically manipulated as well.

Comment: Dear Matthew p, thank you very much for responding to my post. Actually, I have searched for so many posts, but I really didn't find the way to do it. Frankly speaking, I have no idea how to do it. I just need a already cocked code to do the same. I know, it is very hard to get cocked code for the same. But, I appreciate, if you can share any link or any code with me. I am very new to javascript and alfresco but I have a bit idea about programming.